# Kohana-Change password for admin using file driver

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-auth

How can I change the password for a user in kohana, using the file driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Auth file driver the passwords are stored in the Auth config file - `modules/auth/config/auth.php`, so if you want to change user password you have to edit 
that file. By default the content looks like this:

```
return array(

    'driver'       => 'file',
    'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
    'hash_key'     => NULL,
    'lifetime'     => 1209600,
    'session_type' => Session::$default,
    'session_key'  => 'auth_user',

    // Username/password combinations for the Auth File driver
    'users' => array(
        // 'admin' => 'b3154acf3a344170077d11bdb5fff31532f679a1919e716a02',
    ),

);
```

Note that passwords are encrypted with `Auth::hash` method - you have to use it first to get the hash value for your new password.

I you are thinking of letting your users change their password through the website - there is no good way to do it and I'd suggest to switch to ORM driver instead.

Comment: Thanks. There is only one user for the backend and i am trying to change the password. How do I use Auth::hash?

Comment: echo `Auth::instance()->hash('my new password');`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Only thing, I changed  Auth::instance()->hash  to   Auth::instance()->hash_password